# ninject with datacontext and need for static implementation in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I am using a .net standard class library to implement Entity Framework core on an existing ASP.NET MVC web application.
I am injecting the data context into the classes I am using, but I also need a static implementation for some specific method calls. The obvious issue here is that in the static context, I don't have an injected data context. so i did the following.
What is the correct way to do this?
I am using a Ninject Module in the library to map dependencies to the kernel in the web project.

```
namespace AppealTrack.Logic.Classes
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using Common.Entities;
    using Data;
    using Interfaces;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

    public class LookupLogic : ILookupLogic, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly AppealTrackDataContext _context;

        public LookupLogic(AppealTrackDataContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public List<County> GetCountries(string state)
        {
            var list = _context.Countries.Where(x => state == null || x.State == state).Distinct().AsNoTracking().ToList();

            return list;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {

        }
    }

    public static class LookupLogicStatic
    {
        public static List<County> GetCountries(string state)
        {
            // this is the part that I don't think is correct:
            using (var logic = new LookupLogic(new AppealTrackDataContext()))
            {
                var list = logic.GetCountries(state);

                return list;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: public class LogicModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<AppealTrackDataContext>().ToSelf();

            Bind<IAccountTypeLogic>().To<AccountTypeLogic>();
            Bind<ICompanyLogic>().To<CompanyLogic>();
            Bind<IFileTypeLogic>().To<FileTypeLogic>();
            Bind<ILookupLogic>().To<LookupLogic>();
            Bind<IParcelLogic>().To<ParcelLogic>();
            Bind<IPropertyPermissionLogic>().To<PropertyPermissionLogic>();
        }
    }

Comment: Are you able to explain why do you need `LookupLogicStatic` to be static? If you are using DI, you should be injecting `LookupLogic` into consumer classes instead of using its static version. Also can you explain why is `LookupLogic` implementing `IDisposable`? Ninject is responsible for managing the lifetime of your objects so generally speaking, you wouldn't need to explicitly `dispose` them.

Comment: LookupLogic is only implementing IDisposable because I am wrapping it in a using. It's a byproduct of trying to find a solution for this issue. I need a static implementation because we are using DevExpress for MVC and some of the interactivity with their controls forces you to use static methods.

I am using DI, but because of these DevExpress controls, I also have to have some static methods. 

Does ninject provide a way to resolve the data context constructor injection for a static class / method?
If so, how would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you require a static `GetCountries` method, then there is not much you can do... you would need to manage the scope of `DbContext` for that method as static constructor does not take any arguments. Your `LookupLogic` does not **have** to be `Disposable` though (it can be if you want).

If you require a static method, then you don't have to add a new static class, you can add the static method to `LookupLogic`:

```
public class LookupLogic : ILookupLogic
{
    private readonly AppealTrackDataContext _context;

    public LookupLogic(AppealTrackDataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public List<Country> GetCountries(string state)
    {
        return GetCountries(_context, state);
    }

    public static List<Country> GetCountriesStatic(string state)
    {
        using (var dbContext = new AppealTrackDataContext())
        {
            return GetCountries(dbContext, state);
        }
    }

    private static List<Country> GetCountries(AppealTrackDataContext dbContext, string state)
    {
        return dbContext.Countries.Where(x => state == null || x.State == state).Distinct().AsNoTracking().ToList();
    }
}
```